# Error filling data to spinner in android studio

Tags: android, sql, arrays, spinner

I try to filling data to an adapter using android studio and SQLServer, is working but i have a problem, when show the records one of them is lose.
I don't know why!

In sql SELECT placa FROM unidades where modelogps=7; 
show:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLn2f.png)
Code:

```js
Statement comm = conecta().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = comm.executeQuery("SELECT placa FROM unidades where modelogps=7;");
            if (rs.next()) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String id = rs.getString("placa");// value of database
                    data.add(id);
                    ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
                    spinnerlista.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);
                }
            }
```

In spinner show 
[TQ6,
TQ5,
UNAM,
GPORT1,
TRUCKL,
TSM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLn2f.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `if` statement:

```
 if (rs.next())
```

because it makes the resultset to skip the 1st row.
`while (rs.next())` is enough.